# Programm flow is behaving abnormal in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js mvc ie. ui,controller and service. I have written a code that checks whether the same name organization is present in the database or not.
For this purpose I have written an AJAX call. which return me if the name is present in the database or not in the form of '0' or '1'.
ie.'1' for present and '0' for absent. I check this response in the controller and then if the response is one I am returning false to the calling function, but even though everything goes right I still get to see the variable value as 'undefined'.
Following is the code:

**controller:**

```
     $scope.checkOrgName = function(){
         console.log("We are checking id organization name "+$scope.organization.orgName+" is already present in the database or not");
         if($scope.organization.orgName != ""){
             OrganizationService.checkOrgName($scope.organization.orgName).then(
                     function(data){
                         var dbOrgName = data;
                         if(dbOrgName==1){
                           (Command comes here and shows the following alert box on the UI)
                             $scope.failureAlertMessage("This organization name is already present, enter some other name");
                             $scope.organization.orgName = "";
                             return false;(here I am returning false)
                         }
                         else if(dbOrgName==0){
                             console.log("Organization name is available");
                             return true;
                         }
                     },
                     function(errResponse){
                         $scope.failureAlertMessage("Error while checking organization name in the database");
                     }
             );
         }else{
             console.log("No need for the organization name checking, name empty");
         }


     }
```

**calling function (within controller only)**

```
(Here I am calling the above function)
         $scope.orgNameStatus = $scope.checkOrgName();
         console.log("$scope.orgNameStatus: "+$scope.orgNameStatus);(This line prints 'undefined')
          if($scope.orgNameStatus == false){
              return false;
          }
```

**Browser Console:**

```
Inside addOrganization
organization_controller.js:51 We are checking id organization name dsd is already present in the database or not
organization_service.js:25 In service: check org name
organization_controller.js:171 $scope.orgNameStatus: undefined
organization_controller.js:217 Validation status: true
organization_controller.js:59 Command in dbOrgName==1
```

What is wrong with code. Please help me, Thank you.!!

Comment: share a plunk if possible or the statement where this error is happening by checking console.

Comment: I will copy paste console contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `$scope.orgNameStatus` is undefined is that your function `$scope.checkOrgName`does not return any value. You only have a return statement within the `then` callback of the function.

In any case, since the function is asynchrounous, it will only return a *Promise* on which you can register a callback again. You need to make sure that the request is complete before you continue your processing.

**Controller**

```
 $scope.checkOrgName = function(){
     console.log("We are checking id organization name "+$scope.organization.orgName+" is already present in the database or not");
     if($scope.organization.orgName != ""){
// added return statement to return promise
         return OrganizationService.checkOrgName($scope.organization.orgName).then(
                 function(data){
                     var dbOrgName = data;
                     if(dbOrgName==1){
                       (Command comes here and shows the following alert box on the UI)
                         $scope.failureAlertMessage("This organization name is already present, enter some other name");
                         $scope.organization.orgName = "";
                         return false;(here I am returning false)
                     }
                     else if(dbOrgName==0){
                         console.log("Organization name is available");
                         return true;
                     }
                 },
                 function(errResponse){
                     $scope.failureAlertMessage("Error while checking organization name in the database");
                 }
         );
     }else{
         console.log("No need for the organization name checking, name empty");
     }


 }
```

**Calling function**

```
$scope.checkOrgName().then(function(status) {
    $scope.orgNameStatus = status; // now the request is complete and we can assign the status to the scope variable
         console.log("$scope.orgNameStatus: "+$scope.orgNameStatus);(This line prints 'undefined')
          if($scope.orgNameStatus == false){
              return false;
          }
});
```